# How to copy files with a file extension from multiple folders?

Tags: linux, bash

I have to copy files with a `.tmt` extension to a folder(ex: `\main\allfiles\`) from many sub folders under `/individualfiles/1/`, `/individualfiles/2/`, `/individualfiles/abc/`, `/individualfiles/xyz/` ... `/individualfiles/zzz/`.

My issue is after copying all files from one folder, I have to run a java command and then copy again from the next folder and then run the java command again.

We do a copy file by file. After the first file gets copied from `/individualfiles/1/`, we copy the next file from `/individualfiles/1/` and then we go to the next folder `/individualfiles/2/` and again copy files individually.

Please let me know how to run the java command after all files have been copied from a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by stringing together a hand full of linux command line utilities.

Something like this,

```
find . -iname "*.tmt" | xargs dirname | uniq | xargs -I{} sh -c "cp -u {}*.tmt /destination/path && java command.jar"
```

How it works,

1. `find . -iname "*.tmt"` gets all the relative paths with filename of the `.tmt` type from where you run this and the subfolders
2. `xargs dirname` removes the files name leaving you with a list of the relatively pathed directories
3. `uniq` removes duplicate directories
4. `xargs -I{} sh -c "cp -u {}*.tmt /destination/path && java command.jar"` runs a sh script that copies all `.tmt` files in the list of directories with `.tmt` files to a destination folder and if the copy is successful runs `java command.jar` which should be replaced with your java command.

## Edit:

If your goal is to copy 1 file at a time and then run a command after each file is copied that actually simplifies things. The above commands can be reduced to 1 and 4 or this.

```
find . -iname "*.tmt" | xargs -I{} sh -c "cp -u {} /destination/path && java command.jar"
```

This takes every file with the `.tmt` extension found with `find` and runs a script to copy and run java command.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . But as I mentioned above we are copying files one after another . I guess your approach is not as above

Comment: You mentioned needing to copy the files per directory and then run a command. That's what this code does. If you want to individually copy each file and then run a command after each copy I can make a quick edit to the code above for that.

Comment: Yes that would be great.Yes I need to copy single file at a time .

Comment: @user1024962 Please see if my edit's address your problem more accurately. If the edit does help please consider up voting and marking the answer as accepted. (Check mark).